# Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK : Check if a field value is changed in entity

Tags: dynamics-crm

Apart from Plugins, Is there any way to check if value in entity record has changed using C# MS Dynamics CRM SDK? (Online version)

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I have an entity having around 400000 records. An hourly job updates these records. I need to filter out only those records for update where value has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Use an on change of field workflow.
- Use an on change of JavaScript function (client side only).
- Programmatically examine the audit logs.
- Programmatically check for record changes every 5 minutes from an external application.